# BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 Yii2, Android, Volley

Tags: php, android, yii2, android-volley, yii2-basic-app

I am trying to post data from android application to a PHP server running on Yii2 using volley.
For the Volley request, I send using stringRequest:

```
      @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put("name","peter");
            map.put("id","1");
            return map;
        }
```

On the Yii2 side, I use

`http://192.168.43.225/basic/web/index.php?r=user/create`

The application is already working on the web part, the android posting is not working.
ALSO: `jsonArray GET requests` are working as usual and returning json from server, only post requests not working.

Seems like I might end up inserting using `GET` which is a bad idea.

Comment: after use my answer getting error in POST so please mention your whole code of API code which is written in java

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put("name","peter");
            map.put("id","1");
            return map;
        }
```